# How to change local class variable IBAction

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ibaction

everyone!
If anyone can help me i'll be very glad^)

The problem is:
I have IBAction method (checkbox clicking) in my class and i want to change font attribute by clicking the checkbox (into bold state).
I trying to change local class variable in IBAction method for checking it in my - *drawRect:* method, by it's not working - variable doesn't changes.
How to change a local variable in IBAction method or maybe there's another way?
Thanks.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface BigLetterView : NSView {
NSColor *bgColor;
NSString *string;
NSString *testString;
BOOL isHighlighted;
BOOL isBold;
BOOL isItalic;
IBOutlet NSButton *boldButton;
NSMutableDictionary *attributes;

}
@property(retain, readwrite) NSColor *bgColor;
@property(copy, readwrite) NSString *string;
@property(readwrite) BOOL isBold;

- (void)drawStringCenteredIn:(NSRect)r;
- (void)prepareAttributes;
- (void)changeIsBold;
- (IBAction)savePDF:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)makeBold:(id)sender; //it's that method
- (IBAction)setItalic:(id)sender;
```

Here below variable 'isBold' changes to 'YES'. (Method getting called - i test in in debugger).

```
- (IBAction)makeBold:(id)sender
{
if ([boldButton state] == NSOnState) {
isBold = YES;
NSLog(@"Action bold=%d", isBold);
}
else {
isBold = NO;
NSLog(@"Action bold=%d", isBold);
}

}
```

But here isBold is still 'NO' again.

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
NSRect bounds = [self bounds];
[bgColor set];
[NSBezierPath fillRect:bounds];
[self drawStringCenteredIn:bounds];
NSLog(@"isBold: %d",isBold); //HERE prints 'isBold:0'
if (isBold == YES) { 
NSFont *aFont = [attributes objectForKey:NSFontAttributeName];
NSFontManager *fontManager = [NSFontManager sharedFontManager];
[attributes setObject:[fontManager convertFont:aFont toHaveTrait:NSBoldFontMask] forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
}

//whether this view is firstResponder
if ([[self window] firstResponder] == self && 
[NSGraphicsContext currentContextDrawingToScreen]) {
[NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
NSSetFocusRingStyle(NSFocusRingOnly);
[NSBezierPath fillRect:bounds];
[NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];

}
} // drawRect
```

P.S.I doing chapter 20 from Aaron Hillegass book.

Comment: Please show us the code, especially how you make sure that your action method is indeed getting called.

Comment: Thanks for comment,  Ole! Done it.

Answer (score 0):

What you’ve shown so far looks good, but obviously it’s not working or you wouldn’t be here. Try adding this line to the end of your `-makeBold:` method:

```
[self setNeedsDisplay];
```

This will force the view to re-draw itself; it’s possible that your problem is just that the view isn’t being redrawn.

Comment: Thanks for answer, Jeff! Tried it a minute ago. - Nothing changes. Problem's that i try to change variable in IBAction and then check this variable value in another method. Variable changes in IBAction (i print log), but in another method variable's old value.( Looks like variables in IBAction and rest of the class have another memory space..

Comment: How are you creating the view?

Comment: Firstly i created a class, inherited from NSView. And then i dragged 'Custom View' in IB and in Class Identity set default NSView into previously created class.

Comment: I  was helped today. The problem was in my .xib file - i make connection with another superfluous variable of my class instead of connecting with NSView's inherited object. Thanks you nevertheless!!